# Javascript function needs to be called twice to work

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm running a wiki for a Discord bot on Github Pages, and when I try to update the page with code from my pre-made JSON file, it has to be run twice in order to function correctly, it is currently [here](https://nomadiccode.github.io/EveryBot/) and I used the console to run the function. When I run the `addCommands();` function, it returns undefined and does nothing at first, but when I run it the second time, it works

commands.js

```js
var commands_json;

function addCommands() {
  $(function () {
    $.getJSON("./commands.json", function (data) {
      commands_json = data.Commands;
    });
    for (var command in commands_json) {
      console.log(command);
      command_div = document.getElementById("commands");
      command_div.innerHTML +=
        "<div class=" +
        command +
        ' id="command"><h1>' +
        command +
        "</h1><h2>" +
        commands_json[command]["desc"] +
        "</h2><h3>Known Errors: " +
        commands_json[command]["errs"] +
        "</h3></div>";
      if (commands_json[command].subcommands != undefined) {
        for (var subcommand in commands_json[command]["subcommands"]) {
          document.getElementsByClassName(command)[0].innerHTML +=
            "<h4>" +
            subcommand +
            "</h4><h5>" +
            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["desc"] +
            "</h5><h6>Known Errors:" +
            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["errs"] +
            "</h6>";
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

commands.json

```
{
  "Commands": {
    "$decrypt": {
      "desc": "Decrypts a given message with the given key",
      "errs": "There is no error handling to stop it from creating an error if the key fails to decrypt the message"
    },
    "$encrypt": {
      "desc": "Encrypts a message with the given key",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$generatekey": {
      "desc": "Generates an encryption key for encrypting messages",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$eval": {
      "desc": "Evaluates a given expression",
      "errs": "Very strict notation, doesn't accept most symbols such as 2^2 not resulting in 4, while 2**2 results in 4"
    },
    "$meme": {
      "desc": "Using the PRAW library, this command receives the newest post from r/memes",
      "errs": "If the poster deletes their post, only the image is deleted, and the post still remains, therefore it returns an empty embed"
    },
    "$dankmeme": {
      "desc": "Using the PRAW library, this command receives the newest post from r/memes",
      "errs": "Same error as the $memes command"
    },
    "$inventory": {
      "desc": "Opens the user data JSON file and creates an embedding of the items in the user's inventory",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$reset": {
      "desc": "Completely erases the user's account from the user data JSON file",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$shutdown": {
      "desc": "Intended for shutting down the bot while notifying people who are on the \"notifiy\" list",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$ping": {
      "desc": "Returns the bot's responsiveness in seconds, aka ping",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$twitter": {
      "desc": "Part of a list of sub commands that receives tweets from Twitter using Tweepy",
      "errs": "None Known",
      "subcommands": {
        "$twitter trending": {
          "desc": "Takes the WOE (Where On Earth) ID and produces a list of tweets that are trending in that area",
          "errs": "No exception handling for when the WOE ID is incorrect"
        },
        "$twitter user": {
          "desc": "Takes a Twitter username and gets tweets from that person's account",
          "errs": "None known"
        },
        "$twitter hashtags": {
          "desc": "Takes a hashtag and searches any usages of the hashtag",
          "errs": "None known"
        }
      }
    },
    "$reddit": {
      "desc": "Part of a list of sub commands that receives a list of posts from Reddit from the subreddit using PRAW",
      "errs": "None known",
      "subcommands": {
        "$reddit subreddit": {
          "desc": "Takes posts from a subreddit using PRAW",
          "errs": "None known"
        }
      }
    },
    "$pypi": {
      "desc": "Scrapes https://www.pypi.org/ for a packages info",
      "errs": "None known"
    },
    "$status": {
      "desc": "Shows the statuses of the bot and the Discord API",
      "errs": "None known"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $.getJSON is an asynchronous AJAX call. It doesn't return immediately. It makes the call and in it's time, when it's done it will call funcion(data) and set commands_json. After the call and before returning it will continue to the rest of the code, So the for loop will be run BEFORE the $.getJSON returns, and the variable commands_json won't be set yet.
But it will return shortly after. That's why when you call it a second time it works, because by that time $.getJSON has already returned.
So what's the solution ? just put the whole code inside the function(data) and it will work. Because then the code will be run on the return. Like this:

```
var commands_json;

function addCommands() {
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON("./commands.json", function(data) {
            commands_json = data.Commands;
            for (var command in commands_json) {
                console.log(command);
                command_div = document.getElementById("commands");
                command_div.innerHTML +=
                    "<div class=" +
                    command +
                    ' id="command"><h1>' +
                    command +
                    "</h1><h2>" +
                    commands_json[command]["desc"] +
                    "</h2><h3>Known Errors: " +
                    commands_json[command]["errs"] +
                    "</h3></div>";
                if (commands_json[command].subcommands != undefined) {
                    for (var subcommand in commands_json[command]["subcommands"]) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName(command)[0].innerHTML +=
                            "<h4>" +
                            subcommand +
                            "</h4><h5>" +
                            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["desc"] +
                            "</h5><h6>Known Errors:" +
                            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["errs"] +
                            "</h6>";
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the asynchronous function `getJSON`.
You must place all your code inside the callback.

```
function addCommands() {
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("./commands.json", function (data) {
            var commands_json = data.Commands;

            for (var command in commands_json) {
                console.log(command);
                command_div = document.getElementById("commands");
                command_div.innerHTML +=
                    "<div class=" +
                    command +
                    ' id="command"><h1>' +
                    command +
                    "</h1><h2>" +
                    commands_json[command]["desc"] +
                    "</h2><h3>Known Errors: " +
                    commands_json[command]["errs"] +
                    "</h3></div>";
                if (commands_json[command].subcommands != undefined) {
                    for (var subcommand in commands_json[command]["subcommands"]) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName(command)[0].innerHTML +=
                            "<h4>" +
                            subcommand +
                            "</h4><h5>" +
                            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["desc"] +
                            "</h5><h6>Known Errors:" +
                            commands_json[command]["subcommands"][subcommand]["errs"] +
                            "</h6>";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

What's happenning right now is as follows:

- commands_json is declared and has the value `undefined`.
- `addCommands` runs jquery waits for the dom to be ready, after it, it
  executes your function.
- You call getJSON ASYNCHRONOUSLY. Which means
  that the `for` right after it starts to exxecute BEFORE getJSON ends.
- The for executes but, since getJSON haven't finished, commands_json is still undefined and it breaks.
- `getJSON` finishes and saves the result in commands_json
- You run `addCommands` a second time
- `getJSON` is called asynchronously again
- The `for` starts to run before `getJSON` finishes BUT this time `commands_json` has the result of the first call saved.
- The `for` loop works as intended this time
- After this `getJSON` finishes and saves the result in `commands_json` however this value is ignored as the code that uses it has already been executed

Answer (score -2):

Make sure Call a function when the page is ready, see example code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // Call function or write your code here
}, false);
```